# Bitnami Moodle Apache module mod_evasive don't work at all

Tags: security, apache-httpd

I have Debian 9 with Apache/2.4.29 ([Bitnami appliance with Moodle](https://bitnami.com/stack/moodle)). I'm trying to secure web server with mod_evasive and mod_security modules. I installed the module:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive
```

but when I run

```
apacheclt -M | grep eva
```

there is no evasive module. I can see the module mod_evasive20.so in /usr/lib/apache2/modules. Is it possible to somehow enable the module? Thank you

EDIT:
I just run

```
service --status-all
```

to list all running services with their status and this is the output:

```
[ - ]  acpid
[ + ]  atd
[ + ]  bitnami
[ + ]  cron
[ + ]  exim4
[ + ]  haveged
[ - ]  hwclock.sh
[ - ]  irqbalance
[ + ]  kmod
[ + ]  networking
[ + ]  open-vm-tools
[ + ]  procps
[ + ]  proftpd
[ - ]  screen-cleanup
[ + ]  ssh
[ - ]  sudo
[ + ]  syslog-ng
[ + ]  udev
[ + ]  ufw
[ - ]  x11-common
```

As you can see, there is no apache or apache2 service. Is this normal?

EDIT: Yesterday I installed clean Debian 9 with mod_evasive and everything worked at first try, so it's because of bitnami and the differencies in folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you enable apache2 module by command:

```
a2enmod module_name
```

About mod_evasive20 - I've had very serious problems trying to make it work in any way and found newer version of the module in source code form for Apache 2.4. That was the issue - the old=stable=repo version is for Apache 2.0 at its best.

You need to install `apache2-dev` package and compile module by command:

```
apxs -i -a -c mod_evasive24.c
```

Then you need to create configuration file for it and restart apache to make it work.